# Spring transactions - which mode is applied when both are specified in config

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I was trying to debug an issue with legacy code, and chanced upon the fact that the spring configuration file configures the transaction manager in both aspectj and in proxy mode.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" mode="aspectj"/>
```

These configs are in different xml files. Which mode will be picked up by the application? Does it depend on the ordering, or is there a notion of one mode overriding the other?
Thanks!

Comment: If the `mode` is set to `AdviceMode.ASPECTJ`, then the `proxyTargetClass()` attribute is obsolete. Note also that in this case the spring-aspects module JAR must be present on the classpath. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html

Comment: The tx:annotation-driven which controls the transactional capability for all the annotated beans has subtle behavioural differences in these cases.
When the mode="aspectj" the weaving of all transactional behaviour will be based on the pointcuts defined in aj. This looks more like a case of compile time weaving.

Now Spring has great extension that can make auto proxing easier for example:  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true"/> 

In the case of proxy-target-class="true" ,The proxy will get created with the spring dependencies like cglib and this will override the jdk proxying.